# Can I set the twistd pid filename inside the tac configuration file?

Tags: python, twisted, configuration-files, pid, twistd

[I can set the filename of the `.pid` file by supplying the  `--pidfile=` option to `twistd`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/twistd). Is there a way I can specify it inside a `.tac` file instead?

#### Context:

My twisted service is a bot that plays a game and accepts multiple parameters like his name, skill level, etc. I am creating a `.tac` file for each bot (multiple bots can run concurrently) so that each  specific bot always has the same parameters and I can launch it with `twisted -y botname.tac`.

I'd like the pid file to be of the form `<bot_nick>.pid` so that different bots don't use the same pid file and also because I can see which both are running just by listing the pid files. Is there a way I could set this in the `.tac` file itself or do I have to always manually specify it in the twistd command line options like `twistd -y bot1.tac --pidfile=bot1.pid`?

Comment: You may always write a shell wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

A `.tac` file is intended to be a description of a *service that can be run*; whereas the options to `twistd` are options about *how to run a service*.  Therefore it doesn't make sense to put the pidfile filename, or the logging configuration, or anything like that, into a `.tac` file.  In this case, the `.pid` file has *already been written* by the time your `.tac` file is being read, so there is no possible way to do it, even as a workaround.

If you want to write a specialized configuration system, it's better to write a tool that [uses `twistd` like a library, like this example from the `axiomatic` tool that ships with the Axiom database](https://github.com/twisted/axiom/blob/master/axiom/scripts/axiomatic.py#L96-L133).  The interface could stand to be better of course – currently, you actually have to synthesize a literal command line using strings, as well as requiring subclassing – but this lets you have very fine-gained control over *how* your service runs, without trying to hack up other bits of global state just because `.tac` files happen to be Python.